# Can I publish a SWC without publishing a SWF?

Tags: flash, adobe, publish, swc, animate-cc

In Adobe Animate CC, I want to make a SWC so that I can use vector assets in FlashDevelop that were drawn in Animate. However, when I publish my .fla, no .swc is generated unless a .swf is also generated. With Flash unchecked in the Publish Settings, no SWC is created.

[image: Publish Settings with SWC checked and Flash unchecked]

I don't want a .swf. It will just be a confusing unused file cluttering up one of my folders. Is there a way to prevent one from being generated or a way to automatically delete it after the .fla is published?

Comment: Well, probably not. An SWC is actually a archive file that includes the swf. You can rename an SWC into ZIP and view its contents. So basically flash generates an SWF and then packs it into a SWC.

Comment: Hmm, that's good info. Thank you.